# FireDAC Master-Details Cached Updates not work correctly

Tags: delphi, master-detail, firedac

I have problem with master-details in FireDAC. I have four TFDQueries

- master qrPerson
- 3 details qrAddress, qrPhone, qrEmail

For each of them

- SQL is simple query `select * from <table>`
- existing corresponding DataSource
- CachedUpdates = true
- Connection = conMain
- SchemaAdapter = saPerson
- Transaction = trMain
- UpdateTransaction = trMain
- event OnNewRecord for get new ID

For details

- FetchOptions.DetailCascade = true
- Master = dsPerson
- MasterFields = ID_CONTACT
- IndexFieldNames = ID_CONTACT

Before save data I get for each of them `DataSet.State = dsInsert`. I call `qrPerson.Post` (master) and only one detail (qrEmail) has `UpdatesPending = true`. The other two details (qrAddress, qrPhone) have `UpdatesPending = false`. I check events `OnAfterPost` for details and only one was called, `qrEmailAfterPost` of course.

And next `saPerson.ApplyUpdates` and `saPerson.CommitUpdates` save only data for master and one detail.

Summary of my problem:
I insert record to master and also insert records to each of details. All of them have State = dsInsert. After Post on master, only master and one detail save inserted records into database. Two other details forgot inserted data.

Can you help me with this problem? Thanks

Comment: I dont' understand your question, beside you need help. "Not work correctly" is not very descriptive. Maybe you could edit your question with details?

Comment: A master doesn't need to have any detail records. Unless you do something to cause one to be created it won't be.